# Where do you get an Australian outgoing passenger card if checking in online and only having hand luggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, paperwork, australia

I'm aware an Australian incoming passenger card is obtained oboard the aircraft.

What about the outgoing one? I've read "at check-in", but what if you check in online and only have hand luggage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 6/9/17**

I just came back from Melbourne this week and noted that the exit procedures are basically done by a machine that scans your passport.  Once you depart these machines you walk past a small free standing box that has a slot where you are supposed to deposit your exit card.  So there is actually no control over you filling in the card correctly (or at all) and you could probably walk right past it without even depositing anything at all in the box.

This gives me little faith that the information on the exit card is actually used for anything important.

---

**Original Answer**

When departing from (for example) Tullamarine in Melbourne you pass through a set of doors<sup>1</sup> that separates you from the terminal concourse and the departing immigration line.  Just inside these doors, along the wall (and before you line up for immigration) is a bench that has spares of all the required forms you need<sup>2</sup> for departing the country.

You'll also encounter quite a few other people filling out these forms at the last minute!

I expect that this is the same when departing from other Australian airports.

---

<sup>1. You only need a passport and boarding pass to get through this door.</sup>

<sup>2. There should be pens there as well, but I'd bring my own</sup>

Comment: What happens if you forget to fill it out?

Comment: @JonathanReez You'll be stopped and asked to fill it out.  Although since automated immigration gates are now available to all nationalities, dropping the card in the box afterwards is largely on the honor system.

Comment: Will your exit still be recorded properly if you use the SmartGate but don't drop the card in the box?

Comment: Same in Sydney and do I imagine at all international airports in Australia

Comment: You'll be pleased to know that the outgoing passenger card will be [phased out from July 2017](https://www.finder.com.au/outgoing-passenger-card-retiring).

Comment: @k2moo4 missed it by *that* much!   Not that I will miss them.